# Why is my Heroku not deleting after running git remote rm heroku?

Tags: git, heroku

I'm trying to remove a Heroku repo so I can start my Heroku deployment fresh. When I run `git remote -v` I get the Heroku repo:

```
origin  https://<APP_NAME>.herokuapp.com/ (fetch)
origin  https://<APP_NAME>.herokuapp.com/ (push)
```

I deleted the app from my Heroku dashboard and ran `git remote rm https://<APP_NAME>.herokuapp.com/` and get an error:
`fatal: No such remote: https://<APP_NAME>.herokuapp.com/`. I also tried `git remote rm heroku` but got the same result. So I'm confused as to how I can officially delete the Heroku repo so I can start with a fresh Heroku deploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I deleted the app from my Heroku dashboard and ran `git remote rm https://<APP_NAME>.herokuapp.com/` and get an error: `fatal: No such remote: https://<APP_NAME>..herokuapp.com/`

`git rm` takes the *name* of the remote, not its URL. When you ran `git remote -v` you saw:

```
origin  https://<APP_NAME>.herokuapp.com/ (fetch)
origin  https://<APP_NAME>.herokuapp.com/ (push)
```

This tells you that your Heroku remote's name is `origin`. Use that name to remove it:

```
git remote rm origin
```

> I'm confused as to how I can officially delete the Heroku repo so I can start with a fresh Heroku deploy

Your configured remotes actually don't have anything to do with the existence of a Heroku repo. It's a good idea to tidy up your remotes, but `git remote rm` is purely a local operation. Deleting the app in the Heroku dashboard, or via the `heroku` CLI, is sufficient.